# Sql server does not consume memory to Maxlimit

Tags: sql-server, memory-management, ssas

here is the situation
we have 2 TB Memory Installed on Server and 'max Server Memory (MB)'
is set to 1800000 MB.(we tried default limitation(32 TB) also.)  all the time the memory available is 1.7 TB in task manager.it seems sql server not consume memory more than a specif value.
as i know sql server all the time consume memory.
we dataware house with multipe data mart the we full process every 1 hour. some cubes fact are about 100 milion record with 20-30 cuolmns.
i wnat to be sure that sql server and anlysis service can use moery without limitation .are they don't need more than 300 GIG ?i installed some windows application for cunsuming memory  this app can cunsume memory but sql server not.is there any possible test scenario that i cant test to be sure that sql server cant use memory to 1 TB?

Comment: What's the size of the tables that are queried during cube processing? Are they at least 1.8TB?

Comment: it is about 200 GB .processing cube with 50 milion record take 11 minute to process full.

Comment: if the tables are only 200GB then I would assume SQL will consume about 200GB or RAM by the end